# Inserting pictures depending on the day

Tags: vba, excel

I have 7 boxes and I want to insert on each one a different picture depending on the day.

I was wandering if is possible to change the date in the URL automatically for the next 7 days starting from the current day.

```
Sub foto()

With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("http://www.balbala.com/blabla/20180216/balbla/bla")
    With .ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Width = 290
        .Height = 240
    End With
      .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Left
      .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Top
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the line that lists the URL to something like this:

```
With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("http://www.balbala.com/blabla/" & Format(Date(), "yyyymmdd") & "/balbla/bla")
```

Comment: it will be difficult to do an automatic loop for 7 days for 3 month

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub foto()
Dim d As Date
Dim sito(0 To 2) As String
Dim SitoFr As String


sito(0) = "http://www.blabla/blab/
sito(1) = "20180217"
sito(2) = "/blabla/blabla/bl.gpg"

SitoFr = sito(0) + sito(1) + sito(2)


With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(SitoFr)
    With .ShapeRange
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Width = 290
        .Height = 240
    End With
      .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Left
      .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("F3").Top
End With

End Sub
```